# Disable the auto-loading of the videos?

Tags: video

I have a site having lots of videos on its page and it takes a lot of time loading the page because of this. So I want to disable auto-loading of videos on my site.
With this I means is that every time the page is loading I don't want the videos to be loaded which will save me time from loading the page.
Then the specific video will only load if the play button or the video is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The video tag supports a preload attribute which you can set to 'none' - see example from the w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp):

```html
<video controls preload="none">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

However, this does rely on how the browser decides to interpret this and the above link notes that it can be ignored in some circumstances.

A way to control this yourself, is to only display images initially. These can be made to look like video thumbnails and when the user clicks on the image you can then request the video.